# Meaning of SQLIO output "counts per second"

Tags: performance, storage, hardware

I realise that my question isn't strictly 'database' but I know that a lot of DBA's will use the SQLIO tool to check I/O performance on their systems so I'm hoping that somebody here will be able to answer this question:

When I run SQLIO the 3rd line of output says something like:

***using system counter for latency timings, 14318180 counts per second***

What does that mean?  I get different values on different systems, and because I'm comparing different systems I would like to know what that number is telling me (if anything).

Comment: These links will be useful : http://blogs.technet.com/b/josebda/archive/2013/03/28/sqlio-powershell-and-storage-performance-measuring-iops-throughput-and-latency-for-both-local-disks-and-smb-file-shares.aspx and http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlmeditation/archive/2013/04/04/choosing-what-sqlio-tests-to-run-and-automating-sqlio-testing-somewhat.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an informational message, which can be ignored.

This is just the conversion factor between the timer mechanism the program uses internally and actual, real time. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1825720/c-high-precision-time-measurement-in-windows) for a bit of background.

The per-second metrics that the program outputs are the ones you want to focus on. Have a look at [this blog post](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2008/09/finding-your-san-bottlenecks-with-sqlio) for a tutorial on how to use SQLIO and interpret its output.

Comment: Thanks, I was hoping that I could ignore it - there's enough stuff for me to be thinking about with the rest of the information!! :-)

Comment: @JonSeigel Added the links in the comments. Thanks !